# Can I take art gcse?

Tags: halal-haram, quran, hadith, allah, art

Masha Allah I love art and drawing as my favourite hobby and drawing all kind of things (halal ofc). And I am getting a lot of comments from my teachers at school to take art for gcse and I am also considering to do so.

However I’m not sure if I should because some of it would involve drawing haram things (faces, animals, surrealistic artwork and etc…) please could you kindly suggest what I should do and give a few details as why. Thanks very much
May Allah S.W.T guide us all

Comment: Just for amusement: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Boy_Who_Drew_Cats

Comment: are you sure drawing faces, animals, surrealistic are haram?